# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function getradio() in

Tags: php

So I'm getting this error, my company had an online application built.   On our end we usually see the entire application but now I'm only getting to see 1/4 of the application and it gives me a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getradio() in ourwebsite/application.php on line 206

```
<tr>
    <td width="30%" align="left" style="line-height:18px;" class="col_style2">
        <? echo getRadio('Advertisement', $data['f13']); ?><br />
        <? echo getRadio('Employment Agency', $data['f13']); ?>
    </td>
    <td width="30%" align="left" class="col_style2">
        <? echo getRadio('Friend', $data['f13']); ?><br />
        <? echo getRadio('Relative', $data['f13']); ?>
    </td>
    <td width="40%" align="left" class="col_style2">
        <? echo getRadio('Inquiry', $data['f13']); ?><br />
        <? echo getRadio('Other', $data['f13']); ?>, please describe: <? echo $data['f14']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So Line 206 is `<? echo getRadio('Advertisement',$data['f13']); ?><br />`  I'm kind of a new with this and have no idea where to start.  Can anyone give me things to look for or what this means?

Comment: you need to `require` the file where getradio is declared.

Comment: Well there is everything in the error: the function `getRadio()` is undefined. So it's either not included or the file where it was defined was changed

Comment: Where you define getRadio function??

Comment: Where is getradio() function file ??

Comment: where is line no 206 ? Please check all attach files

Comment: Thanks guys, ohh man I'm not sure where the getRadio is defined.   I have to somehow find where this application posts too I guess.   It's probably another file not the database right?

Comment: It will most probably be in a file. Heaven help you if it's in the DB ;)

Comment: search in your project files for "function getradio"